# media query with jquery

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I would like to check if it’s possible to add media query.

For example,
if the window size is between 700px to 1000px, then change certain text of hyperlink (with class name : ‘samplebutton’ from ‘ABC’ to ‘DEF’.

I got something like this… but it throws an error.. not sure what went wrong..

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if($(window.width()) >= 700) {        
        jQuery('a.samplebutton').text("DEF");   
    }   
});

</script>
```

I am not well-verse in programming but if you could show some sample lines of code, I will be able to take it from there… Can you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the content of any element when the screen size changes, you need to use an event listener.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  /* Prints the current mode and screen width. */
  function log(width, mode) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Mode: ${mode} Width: ${width}px`);
  }

  /* This method is called when the resize event is triggered. */
  function update(object) {
    let width = object.width();
    let mode;
    
    $('#result').text(`${width}px`);
    
    /* Dekstop Mode */
    if(width >= 1024) {
      mode = 'Desktop';
      $('#engine').text('Google');
    }
    /* Tablet Mode */
    else if(width < 1024 && width > 768) {
      mode = 'Tablet';
      $('#engine').text('Google');
    }
    /* Mobile Mode */
    else if(width <= 768) {
      $('#engine').text('Yahoo');
      mode = 'Mobile';
    }
    
    log(width, mode);
  }

  /* The resize event fires when the page width changes. */
  $(window).on('resize', function(){        
    update($(this));
  }); 
  
  update($(this));
});
```

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
.samplebutton {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Page Width: </span>
<p id="result"></p><hr>

<a id="engine" class="samplebutton" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```